# Guess the Vocabulary Word!

Tags: riddle, word

Here is a short riddle that randomly popped into my head. Enjoy! :)

> At first you might want to run away from me.
>
> Then, you might confuse me with a female hoofed ruminant.
>
> Only to realize I finish with a plural name for a dude.
>
> Even though I may be all of these things,
>
> I am ultimately something that a lot of people want to work on and something that everybody has.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are:

> Abdomen

Prefix:

> AB but not sure why **EDIT** Ab is Latin meaning "Away From", courtesy of @Crozier

Infix:

> A female deer is a Doe, hence DO

Suffix:

> Plural for a dude, dude is a man, so plural is MEN

Whole:

> Lots of people work out their abdomens to get rock hard abs, and everyone has them.

Comment: Wow, that was fast! You are correct! The prefix ab- means "away from" in Latin. Also, welcome to Puzzling Stack Exchange! :) @AHKieran

Comment: Yay and thank you! I hardly know any latin so thanks for that :) And I'm having a lovely time here, started a new job recently and it helps me pass the time whilst tests are running whilst still keeping my brain active :D @Crozier